# What doesn't margin-right and width:100% overflow child to the left?

Tags: html, css

I have difficulty understanding why CSS works this way for what I am trying.

Suppose I have an outer and inner div. The inner div has width:100% and margin-left:150px; In this case the inner div overflows to the right. My understanding is the inner div gets 100% width of outer div and margin-left pushes it outside the parent.

However, if I change margin-left of the inner div to margin-right I don't see it overflowing to the left (div outer1 and inner1). I checked in the dev tool and see that inner1 has a 150px margin added to the right but that doesn't seem to do anything. Why does this happen, and what happens to margin-right?

[image]

```css
 .outer {
      width:50vw;
      height:50vh;
      background-color:black;
      margin:auto;
    }
    
    .inner {
      width:100%;
      height:50%;
      background-color:pink;
      margin-left:150px
     
    }
    
    .outer1 {
  width:50vw;
  height:50vh;
  background-color:violet;
  margin:auto;
}

.inner1 {
  width:100%;
  height:50%;
  background-color:yellow;
  margin-right:150px
 
}
```

```html
      
    <div class="outer">
      <div class="inner">
        <p>Inside parent container(not body), width:100% ; margin-left ; overflow to the right
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="outer1">
  <div class="inner1">
    <p>Inside parent container(not body), width:100% ; margin-right ; doesnt overflow to the left
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#blockwidth):

> If all of the above have a computed value other than 'auto', the values are said to be "over-constrained" and **one of the used values will have to be different from its computed value**. If the **'direction' property of the containing block has the value 'ltr**', **the specified value of 'margin-right' is ignored** and the value is calculated so as to make the equality true. If the value of 'direction' is 'rtl', this happens to 'margin-left' instead.

`margin-right` is ignored in the the ltr configuration. Change the direction and the same will happe with `margin-left`

```css
.outer {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vh;
  background-color: black;
  margin: auto;
  direction: rtl;
}

.inner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: pink;
  margin-left: 150px
}

.outer1 {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vh;
  background-color: violet;
  margin: auto;
  direction: rtl;
}

.inner1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin-right: 150px
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <p>Inside parent container(not body), width:100% ; margin-left ; overflow to the right
  </div>
</div>

<div class="outer1">
  <div class="inner1">
    <p>Inside parent container(not body), width:100% ; margin-right ; doesnt overflow to the left
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks . Is there a way to see the used value in Chrome inspector ? I see the computed value only for margin-right: 150px which confused me .

Comment: @Knownow I don't think it's possible. but always keep in mind that in some rare case, the used value can be different. They are not a lot by the way